# Which Captain is older in Star Trek VII?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-generations

In [Star Trek : Generations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/), who is older, Captain Picard or Captain Kirk?

[image]

Comment: If this question wants to ignore Kirk's time in the Nexus, that should be noted. Obviously, it would be a game-changer if included.

Comment: @Omegacron - Don't get me started on the fact that Picard has been whisked all around time by Q, not to mention various temporal loops, etc.

Comment: I can't remember if they explicitly say it in the movie but I think it was at least presumed that time does not affect those stuck in the Nexus.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer - Guinan says it doesn't; *"And from his point of view, he just got there too."*. Kirk entered The Nexus in 2293 and exited in 2371. From his subjective perspective, only a few minutes passed.

Comment: @Richard - lol, that IS true. However, if we stick with age according to linear timeline, the fact that Kirk was essentially in stasis for 70+ years would definitely make him the older of the two. If we're ignoring that period and only counting "active" years, Picard is the older of the two.

Comment: @Omegacron - I was wondering whether the fact that Picard has been trapped inside time-loops would make a substantial difference to his real age.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Picard is chronologically the elder, by 6 years.

James T. Kirk was born in 2233 and was reported dead in 2293 (when he entered the Nexus) at **60** years of age.

Jean-Luc Picard was born in 2305. Since Star Trek : Generations takes place in 2371, that makes him **66** years of age.

---

Out-of-universe, it's perhaps worth noting that at the time of filming, neither actor was portraying their correct age. Patrick Stewart was actually 54 and William Shatner was 63.

Comment: What's scary is that Mr. Stewart already looked like 60 when he was 41 ("Excalibur"). Luckily he doesn't look much older now that he's 74.

Comment: But Damon, Patrick Stewart hasn't showed signs of aging in 25 years.

Comment: @Damon - Queen Elizabeth hates him so much, she tried to chop his head off; http://moviecitynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/patrick-stewart-knighted.jpg

Comment: Patrick Stewart is a little like Anthony Hopkins, Tommy Lee Jones, and Ian Holm, in terms of his ageing pattern.  When they were middle-aged, they all looked older than their age, but they seemed to stop ageing any further after that!  (And they are all still alive: Patrick Stewart is currently 74, Anthony Hopkins is 77, Tommy Lee Jones is 68, and Ian Holm is 83!)

Comment: Also, I was always a little shocked about how dramatically different William Shatner looked between TOS and The Motion Picture....

Comment: See Patrick Stewart as Sejanus in "I, Claudius" for a PS with hair (ca 1975).