# Could Captain Kirk have lived long enough to meet Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos

I guess I should say ***SPOILER ALERT*** if you haven't seen *Star Trek Generations* or the reboot films.

In the movie [*Star Trek Generations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations), Captain Kirk and Captain Picard meet to defeat Soran.  According to the wiki, Kirk captains the *Enterprise-B* in year 2293 and Picard captains the *Enterprise-D* in 2371 (78 years later).

Would Captain Kirk have been alive when Picard was alive if he had not gone into the Nexus (per *Star Trek Generations*)?

Comment: What is unclear about _"Would Kirk have been alive when Picard was alive?"_

Comment: The answer to the question is: No, they would not have met in an unaltered timeline. The reason this is so is because, as we found out in [this Q/A](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78932/which-captain-is-older-in-star-trek-vii), Picard would have been 66 when he entered the Nexus. Kirk entered the Nexus 78 years prior to this. Picard wasn't even born yet.

Comment: But the Nexus canon is out with the reboot technically so since Kirk was still healthy at the time, and Picard was only born 12 years after that year...

Comment: But you stated (in parenthesis) *in an unaltered timeline* ... you are not helping to reopen your own question.

Comment: @Paulster2 hes asking is it possible for kirk and picard to meet had kirk not gone through the nexus, as would kirk have died of old age before being able to meet picard, and in the new universe this is a possibility, that if he lives long enough he will meet picard. (assuming picard is born)

Comment: @Himarm ... then I would have closed this question as well as unclear what's being asked.

Comment: Updated Q for all you great close voters.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - If five people in a row think a question is unclear, it's usually a good sign that the question is unclear.

Comment: @Richard i thought his original was unclear, but hes right about wondering whats unclear about asking if kirk would have still been alive when picard was alive, im not sure how much clearer it can be asked.

Comment: It's down to the writers if (reboot)Kirk goes into the Nexus. We've no way of knowing. Also, (reboot)Kirk will never meet (original)Picard since they're in different universes.

Comment: @Richard Still a valid Q on whether or not Kirk and Picard were alive at the same time (or could be alive at the same time)

Comment: @Chrismas007 I'd recommend rewording that last piece.  Make it simply, 'is it possible for the new Kirk to live until Picard in the new timeline is alive?'  Blending the new and original timelines in that question makes it muddled and unclear.

Comment: @Keen you good with Himarm's edit?

Comment: @Keen - But then it become trivia, basically the edited question boils down to "*Is it possible for someone to live to the age of 72?*"

Comment: @Richard LMK when we ban trivia from the site.

Comment: @Keen - Good trivia, yes. Not mindless trivia.

Comment: Why is the “within the reboot films…” paragraph here? What does the question have to do with the reboot?

Comment: It's all pure conjecture based on the question ... I don't see how it could be construed as anything but opinion because we have yet to figure out what the reboot is going to do and it *would not* have occurred in the original universe.

Comment: Think of all the ways the enterprise crew has managed to lose / gain time, slip through temporal anomalies, etc. Anymore, there may not even be a natural timeline. We've seen the crew rapidly age, return to normal, go back to the 20's, see a future of a whole borg earth. So yeah, it's very possible in their universe.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - "But the Nexus canon is out with the reboot technically" - this statement is categorically incorrect. Even the 2009 movie states that the events in the reboot are an alternate timeline - not an alteration of the prime universe.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Admiral Dr. McCoy inspects the Enterprise D in [the first episode of TNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint), he is 137 years old at this point. So I hazard to guess if nothing had happened and Kirk lived a long life he would have possibly been alive when Picard was captain of the Enterprise.

Kirk would have been 72 when Picard was born, so its also not unreasonable that Picard could have meet Kirk as a child, or first entering Starfleet.

Also as ThePopMachine mentions, Dr. McCoy is older then Kirk anyway, which would give Kirk more leeway in age if Dr. McCoy was at the extent of human life expectancy.

Comment: (also, of course, in *Star Trek*, **anything** is possible, so obviously the answer is yes.)   :)

Comment: If this answer hadn't been here, I'd have had to add it.  Kirk was significantly younger than McCoy, yet McCoy did visit the Enterprise D in the first season of TNG.  Even fifteen years later, it's very reasonable that a geriatric Kirk might still have been around.

Comment: Kelley (McCoy) was 67 at the time, so we can estimate that lifespan has roughly doubled by then.

Comment: As I recall the Shatnerverse novel The Return has McCoy comment that most of his organs have been replaced by the time of the TNG films.  Cloned replacement intestines specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If in real life as a young man William Shatner can play Fictional Captain Kirk then in his 90s actually go to space and in this century actors like Betty White are acting into their 100s and presidents are leading the free world into their 80s & Queens are Reigning into their 90s, then I think that in 100 years, a prestigious Captain that heads the flagship of the most important “country” at the time probably has the best health care there is like the 1% has today. I 100% expect a young officer, possibly even a young captain Picard could cross paths with an elderly Admiral Kirk,

Comment: I don't disagree with your conclusion, but I think your argument would be stronger if you based it on in-universe evidence -- as the [accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79382/122024) did -- rather than real world evidence.

Comment: Betty White died at age 99.